# Unstretched Generated texture coordinates for Normal Mapping

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, node-editor

I'm trying to figure out the proper way of generating a UV map that does not distort.

I'm trying to generate a UV map to place a normal map on top of, that doesn't stretch to the vertices of the mesh. See image 4 where it naturally stretches to the X and Y dimensions of the mesh.

Is there a better way of doing this? It seems to have worked in image 5, but I would prefer to have it be exactly squares.

Also, is it possible to have the floor be slightly glossy so that this normal disrupts its perfect surface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Object Coordinates](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html?#texture-coordinate-node) to get a undistorted UV map without manually unwrapping the model.

Unlike the *Generated* coordinates which stretch to whatever size the mesh is (even if the object's scale is set to 1), object coordinates always stay square.

Here is a plane with generated coordinates.
[image: plane with generated coordinates]

Same plane now with object coordinates.
[image: plane with object coordinates]

Answer (score 4):

Go into top view, select all vertices, and pres <kbd>U</kbd> *> Project From View*

[image: Project From View]

This will work excellently as this is just a plane. All you then need to do is change the texture coordinates in you material from *Generated* (your current setting) to *UV*.

[image: UV Coordinates]

---

To add some gloss, just mix your diffuse with a *Glossy BSDF* shader with the same color input, like so:

[image: Mix Shaders]

You can then edit the *Factor* of the *Mix* node to decide how much gloss, and the *Roughness* of the glossy shader to determine the sharpness of the reflections.

Comment: Okay I'll give that a go!

Comment: It doesn't seem to have worked
http://i.imgur.com/syStsBD.jpg

Comment: @Peter Mapping node goes before image texture, image texture color goes into both glossy and diffuse. That should fix it. Let me know if it does

Comment: @NovieInDisguise But if I connect the Image Texture Color to my Glossy BSDF then I lose the specific color in the glossy shader... as it gets replaced by the color of the image texture

Comment: I misunderstood, color has nothing to do with it, I thought you wanted to color it. Should be fine. I just find it easier to blend it (depending on the circumstances) if I use the same colors, or at least derive them from the same input.

Comment: Migrated to (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26403/slight-variance-in-floor-normal-mapping)

Answer (score 1):

You can also manually set the texture space to be square again.

Before any change:

[image: Plane with a stretched checker texture]

To fix it, you should:

1. Select the object.
2. Go to Object data tab.
3. Uncheck `Auto Texture Space`.
4. Make sure that all size dimensions have the value 1.

[image: Properties before fixing it]

[image]

And this is the result:

[image]